# Intelephense bugs in VSCode

Tags: php, oop, error-handling, intelephense

Intelepense in VScode tells me that — Undefined variable '$name'.intelephense(1008). Same with $age.
And in the inherited class, there is an error with the parent:: construct - Cannot use 'parent' in a class with no parent.intelephense(1035).
I checked in PhpStorm, everything worked as it should.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlS5n.png)

Comment: Please also post the relevant code as _text_, not just a picture - see [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: This is definitely a bug.  My base class exists, I can hit F12 while the cursor is in the base class name and it opens the file.  But for some reason, the `__construct()` method can't find its parent.

Comment: FYI  - Got this via a colleague encountering this. He didn't have a namespace resolver. In VS Code we installed Mehedi Hassan's "PHP Namespace Resolver" extension and it can now traverse between classes & thus Inteliphense also doesn't show this error anymore.